# How to search by joined table's word and get all the relative data from joined table by cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

My Circumstance:
php 5.1.6
cakephp 1.3

I have a Restaurant table whose structure is like bellow.

```
id       name        
1    Italian_resto
2    French_resto
3    Japanese_resto
```

I also have a RestaurantsTag table whose structure is like bellow.

```
id   restaurant_id  type       tag      
1         1         area     Firenze
2         1　　　　　genre    Italian
3         2         area     Paris
4         2         genre    French
5         3         area     Tokyo
6         3         genre    Japanese
```

These two table can be joined by Restaurant.id and RestaurantsTag.restaurant_id. 
Then, I'd like to get all the tags which belong to Italian_resto when I search tags by "Italian". In other words, when I search tag by 'Italian', I'd like to get 'Italian' and 'Firenze' whose restaurant_ids are both 1 . The result I want is bellow.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Restaurant"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Italian_resto"

    }
    ["RestaurantsTag"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "genre"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(12) "Italian"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "area"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(6) "Firenze"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result bellow is also welcome.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Restaurant"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Italian_resto"

    }
    ["RestaurantsTag"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "genre"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(12) "Italian"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Restaurant"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(27) "Italian_resto"

    }
    ["RestaurantsTag"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(5) "area"
        ["tag"]=>
        string(12) "Firenze"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

How can I achieve that by one query in cakephp 1.3?
If It is not possible, how can I achieve that by the simplest queries?

Comment: Basically you want a mysql query? I have not experience with cakephp. I can give you a mysql query which can give you the information you want

Comment: @Sohaib Basically I want cakephp code, but If you are not familiar with cakephp, the mysql query is also welcome. Then I will try to figure out how to do that in cakephp. The suggestion to the tables' structures are also welcome, because currently, those tables' structures are changeble

Comment: Could you clearly define your input. What is the exact query. Is tag=Italian the only thing provided?

Comment: @Sohaib Yes, tag=Italian is the only thing provided.

Comment: What if tag=Italian was also present in resId 2 what is the desired output in such a scenario?

Comment: @Sohaib Then I want the data where Restarant.id = 2 from Restaurant Table, and all the tags where RestarantsTag.restairant_id = 2. The tags I get should be 'Paris','French' and 'Italian'

Comment: Did you even try something and failed?

Comment: @skywalker I tried customizing find and joins' conditions, using hasMany in the model,  but curently, nothing works out.

Comment: Post what you have done so far, you will get help more likely that way instead of asking for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the required input and output something like this is possibly what you want.

```
SELECT rt.res_id, rt.`type`, rt.tag, r.res_name FROM
restaurants_tag rt
JOIN 
    (SELECT res_id FROM restaurants_tag WHERE tag="Italian") d 
ON d.res_id = rt.res_id 
JOIN restaurant r ON d.res_id = r.id;

|res_id |type   |tag        |res_name
|-------|-------|-----------|------------
|1      |area   |Firenze    |Italian_resto
|1      |genre  |Italian    |Italian_resto
```

Feel free to revert if this is not what you want.

Comment: Thaks really. I will try your code and convert it into a cakephp code.

Comment: @Sho If you find it useful don't forget to mark as correct :)

Comment: +1 I tested this code in my circumstance. As long as I see the result, this code works fine. Thanks a lot!  If I manage to convert your sql code to cakephp code,  I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to start with something like this:

```
SELECT a.restaurant_id
     , b.name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'area' THEN tag END) area
     , MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'genre' THEN tag END) genre 
  FROM restaurant_tags a 
  JOIN restaurants b 
    ON b.id = a.restaurant_id 
 GROUP 
    BY a.restaurant_id;
```

or

```
SELECT x.restaurant_id
     , x.tag area
     , y.tag genre 
  FROM restaurant_tags x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN restaurant_tags y 
    ON y.restaurant_id = x.restaurant_id 
   AND y.type = 'genre'
  JOIN restaurants r
    ON r.id = x.restaurant_id
 WHERE x.type = 'area';
```

This particular version of this query assumes that `area` will always be present, but it can be rewritten if that's not the case